# Handling multiple Xib or fixing collapse and expand button on multiple Xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, view, xib

Now the situation is illustrated in this image:

[image]

I have an app having multiple Xib files calling in one main Xib and its class. I have added expand and collapse view which works on particular xib expand and collapse subviews as required and reduces/Expands Height too.

This works well for one xib section when all tabs of xib files are collapsed and the second xib won't change its y-coordinates, but I'm having a white space between. I want to fix it.

Note: Every xib contains a class referring to it. The whole app won't use auto-resize.

How can I solve this?

Comment: @Shebin Koshy here is matter waiting for your reply and others too

Comment: I think you should use autolayout and reszie height of xibs when any of them is added or removed

Comment: whole app is not coded by me and Auto-Layout is disabled for all , i have to fix soon ,but im helpless

Comment: i was thinking for a method  which can called during button pressed then which set x and Y coordinates accordingly

Comment: you have got idea why not implement it ?

Comment: i'm new to ios don't know which function will do it , and how each class will call in itself bcoz function will exist in main class ..

Comment: can you post your xib's code. I'll  see if I can help

Comment: @Misha Codes are too much long cant be posted , for now i added code of uibutton which set collapse and expands are here [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176153/working-with-one-xib-with-multiple-classes?noredirect=1#comment52239332_32176153)

Comment: @iDeepak Did u run the app and take screenshot or u take screenshot from ur xib/nib file viewer?