# Working with One Xib with Multiple Classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have already asked a question here [Handling Multiple Xib or Fixing collapse and expand button on multiple Xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155915/handling-multiple-xib-or-fixing-collapse-and-expand-button-on-multiple-xib-file)
then I thought to stop using multiple xib and only main xib with different classes but is it possible ??
Can someone guide me in way which is possible for me to do ?

Please help me to fix it

Code for UIbutton im using

```
- (IBAction)btnPupl:(UIButton *)sender {
CGRect rect;
 sender.selected = !sender.selected;


if(sender.selected ){


[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus_1.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    pView.hidden = true;
    eomView.hidden = true ;
    eomLable.hidden = true;

        rect = pupileomMainView.frame;
        rect.size.height = rect.size.height - eomView.frame.size.height ;
        pupileomMainView.frame = rect;



    rect = pSepLine1.frame ;
    rect.origin.y = pupileomMainView.frame.size.height + pupileomMainView.frame.origin.y  ;
    pSepLine1.frame = rect ;

    rect = pSepLine2.frame ;
    rect.origin.y = pSepLine1.frame.origin.y +6 ;
    pSepLine2.frame = rect;

    rect = ExternalMainView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = pSepLine2.frame.origin.y + 1;
    ExternalMainView.frame = rect;

    rect = eSepLine1.frame;
    rect.origin.y = ExternalMainView.frame.origin.y + ExternalMainView.frame.size.height  ;
    eSepLine1.frame = rect;

    rect = eSepLine2.frame;
    rect.origin.y = eSepLine1.frame.origin.y + 5 ;
    eSepLine2.frame = rect ;

    rect = laMainView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = eSepLine2.frame.origin.y + 1;
    laMainView.frame = rect;

    rect = laSepLine1.frame;
    rect.origin.y = laMainView.frame.origin.y +laMainView.frame.size.height  ;
    laSepLine1.frame = rect ;

    rect = laSepLine2.frame ;
    rect.origin.y = laSepLine1.frame.origin.y + 5 ;
    laSepLine2.frame = rect ;

    rect = iopMainView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = laSepLine2.frame.origin.y +1;
    iopMainView.frame = rect;

    rect = iopSepLine1.frame;
    rect.origin.y = iopMainView.frame.origin.y + iopMainView.frame.size.height ;
    iopSepLine1.frame = rect ;

    rect = iopSepLine2.frame;
    rect.origin.y = iopSepLine1.frame.origin.y + 5;
    iopSepLine2.frame = rect;

    rect = sleMainView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = iopSepLine2.frame.origin.y + 1 ;
    sleMainView.frame = rect;

    rect = sleSepLine.frame;
    rect.origin.y = sleMainView.frame.size.height + sleMainView.frame.origin.y ;
    sleSepLine.frame = rect;

    rect = sleSepLine2.frame;
    rect.origin.y = sleSepLine.frame.origin.y +5;
    sleSepLine2.frame = rect;

    rect = fundusMainView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = sleSepLine2.frame.origin.y + 1;
    fundusMainView.frame = rect;

    rect= fundusSepLine1.frame;
    rect.origin.y = fundusMainView.frame.origin.y + fundusMainView.frame.size.height ;
    fundusSepLine1.frame = rect ;

    rect= fundusSepLine2.frame;
    rect.origin.y = fundusSepLine1.frame.origin.y+5 ;
    fundusSepLine2.frame = rect ;

    rect = self.examView.frame;
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height - eomView.frame.size.height;
    self.examView.frame = rect;
}

else {

    pView.hidden = false;
    eomView.hidden = false;
    eomLable.hidden = false;

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minus_round_d1.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];




    rect = pupileomMainView.frame;
    rect.size.height =  rect.size.height + eomView.frame.size.height  ;
    pupileomMainView.frame = rect;

    rect = pSepLine1.frame ;
    rect.origin.y = pupileomMainView.frame.size.height + pupileomMainView.frame.origin.y +1 ;
    pSepLine1.frame = rect ;

    rect = pSepLine2.frame ;
    rect.origin.y = pSepLine1.frame.origin.y +6 ;
    pSepLine2.frame = rect;

    rect = ExternalMainView.frame;
    rect.origin.y = pSepLine2.frame.origin.y + 1;
    ExternalMainView.frame = rect;

    rect = eSepLine1.frame;
```

Comment: this question needs to be clarified:  do you want different Objective-C classes to all use a single XIB file? or multiple XIB files being called from a single Objective-C class?

Comment: thank you for reply actually look at my older question

Comment: which having a white space issue if it got resolved by another way then i dont need other methods

Comment: @iDeepak I don't think its a problem of handling multiple XIBs, there is a problem with your implementation. Can you put your code here?

Comment: whole code ??? it contains much more codec cant put here

Comment: @iphonic code of what particular section like button which collapsing ??

Comment: @iDeepak Show code, of how you are adding and collapsing.

Comment: @iphonic thank for reply here is code im using for uibutton which doing collapse and expands added to question

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). This is the idea that multiple classes can be sent the same message, (and potentially behave in different ways). You can create a class like: `BaseViewController` that would have the definition for `btnPupl:(id)sender` in the `@interface`. This way any view controller that inherits from `BaseViewController` will inherit `btnPupl:(id)sender`.

Another option (I'd go with the first one) is to subclass `UIButton` and implement the behaviour you want in that subclass.